# docker build inside docker build

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Tl;Dr; **What is the equivalent of docker run -v for docker build?**

I have created a test case including two steps:

- building a docker image using a Dockerfile
- running a command using the docker image just created

This works well but I am now considering how to run it from 
within our Jenkins CI setup.

We have a Dockerfile which Jenkins uses to set-up the build
environment and to run the tests so I have a *docker in docker* situation.

I have read the usual advice, including https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/
but am still somewhat stumped by the basics.
I think the discussions tend to focus on "docker run" inside "docker run"
whereas I want "docker build, then docker run" inside "docker build"

To keep things simple I am ignoring the Jenkins part for now and I've cut my Dockerfile back to
to a minimum which I build using:

```
docker build -t minimal -f Dockerfile.minimal .
```

I can create a docker image which can almost run docker.

My first problem is that the output of running a "docker run" is not echoed to the terminal

```
RUN docker -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock run hello-world
```

runs apparently successfully but all I see is:

```
Step 10/10 : RUN docker -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock run hello-world
 ---> Running in 6334040920e9
Docker version 18.09.3, build 774a1f4
Removing intermediate container 6334040920e9
 ---> bd3eaf625228
```

Rather than:

```
>docker run -t hello-world

Hello from Docker!
...
```

**I want to build the image in the parent context as a sibling rather than a child. A problem is "docker build" does not have a -v option.**
So at the moment I have:

```
Step 12/12 : RUN docker build -f Dockerfile .
---> Running in cb45800fb1cf
```

error checking context: 'can't stat '/proc/1/map_files''.
   The command '/bin/sh -c docker build -f Dockerfile .' returned a non-zero code: 1

My current minimal Dockerfile is:

```
FROM debian:9

RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y gpg-agent apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg2 software-properties-common
RUN curl -XGET -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian $(lsb_release -cs) stable" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y install docker-ce

RUN whoami
VOLUME /var/run/docker.sock
RUN docker --version
RUN docker -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ps
RUN sh -c '(docker -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock run hello-world)'

COPY Dockerfile2 Dockerfile
RUN docker build -f Dockerfile .
```

where Dockerfile2 is even more minimal:

```
FROM debian:9
RUN echo "hello world"
```

This may be a duplicate of [Access docker within Dockerfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53740182/access-docker-within-dockerfile) which says this is not possible but perhaps Docker has evolved since that question was answered?

Comment: If you could provide a more clear rationale behind why you're trying to do this - maybe we could come up with a simpler solution

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. Even if it was, it sounds like it might be overcomplicated.

If you'd like to do something a little better than a DinD (Docker-in-Docker) - you can try [building your images with buildah](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/08/14/best-practices-for-running-buildah-in-a-container/) which does not require a Docker daemon (hence - is safer) to build an image and performs better (at least for me) than what I saw with DinD scenarios.