# Run script before every RUN in Dockerfile?

Tags: bash, docker

I have a bit of a weird situation where I need to source the output of a script to set up some environment variables (which are only known at build time) before several RUN steps in my Dockerfile.

I know I can do this:

```
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"] 
RUN source <(./my_script) && echo "step 1"
RUN source <(./my_script) && echo "step 1"
```

And so on. But is there any way I can avoid repeating the `source` for every step?

Comment: Can’t you use `.bashrc` for that purpose?

Comment: Are you sure you want `source <(./my_script)`, not `source ./my_script` ?

Comment: @Philippe Yes, that is a Python program that outputs a Bash script. I don't control this program.

Answer (score 1):

Create a script named `my_source` with following content :

```
unset BASH_ENV
source <(./my_script)
```

Then in you Dockerfile :

```
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
ENV BASH_ENV "./my_source"

COPY my_script my_source ./

RUN echo "$VAR_DEFINED_IN_my_script"
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to avoid this with `ARG` and `ENV`, running the script in the host env

```
ARG VALUE_A="${VALUE_A}"
ENV VALUE_A=$VALUE_A
```

More details at [How do I copy variables between stages of multi stage Docker build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52904847/how-do-i-copy-variables-between-stages-of-multi-stage-docker-build)

Otherwise you run into https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/29110 ([from Answer to Dockerfile - set ENV to result of command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41864647/4541045))

beware: this will not be sufficient if the script isn't only used for env vars, but does other work, such as modifying some shell defaults, creating or overriding functions, refreshing time-bound or other limited-use credentials, etc.

(obligatory PSA to take extreme caution with credentials in Docker as they may be visible to anyone with the container)

---

For completeness, it possible to hack around many limitations of Dockerfiles by providing your container access to the docker daemon

While this sounds neat, and allows you to go so far as to execute an arbitrary script which results in a new, dynamic `Dockerfile` which you can immediately run .. I don't and can't possibly recommend this route in vanilla docker due to all of its maintainabiltiy and security flaws

<strike>Details</strike> warnings here about doing this *without* `compose` and `buildkit` (also requires host/OS changes) [Access docker within Dockerfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53740182/access-docker-within-dockerfile)

A similar procedure is *much* safer and borderline useful with `docker compose` and buildkit (in such a context, you *can* provide access to the docker socket!), but still not generally recommendable.. still, going with `docker compose` can give you more useful tools in general to provide env values, but is not always possible

Comment: I'd argue that this doesn't answer the question. `source`ing a script can do plenty of things other than defining environment variables -- it might be setting up shell functions, or turning on non-default options (enabling aliases, or setting the `globfail` flag, or doing other process-local setup); the utility of this answer is dependent on unfounded assumptions about the limits of what the OP is trying to accomplish.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy certainly for the general case, but they specifically noted their purpose is "_to set up some environment variables_"!

Comment: Fair enough. (Mind, it still depends on what those variables are -- if the Python script is going to a secret store, receiving time-bounded credentials and putting them in the environment for use during the current build step, the OP's original approach may still make sense).

Comment: indeed - I'll add something about that!